# Ubuntu 15.10 all HDMI options show "unplugged"

Tags: sound, 15.10, hdmi

I tried the answer shown in [Ubuntu thinks HDMI audio is unplugged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583284/ubuntu-thinks-hdmi-audio-is-unplugged), but all the options show as "unplugged." How can I get an option that's not "unplugged"?

The video works fine, but not the audio.

[image]